# What's the difference between these two code for inference with toy MNIST example

Tags: pytorch, mnist

I found that there're different accuracy values between those two codes.
I think that those are the same codes but give different values.
Why are the results of the two codes different?

**[ code 1 ]**

```
def mytest(model, data_loader):
    with torch.no_grad():
        corrected_sample = 0
        for x_test, y_test in data_loader:
            x_test, y_test = x_test.to(device), y_test.to(device)
            x_test = x_test.view(-1,28*28).float()
            prediction = model(x_test)
            #predicted_class = prediction.max(1)[1]
            predicted_class = torch.argmax(prediction, 1)
            corrected_sample += (predicted_class==y_test).float().sum().item()
    accuracy = corrected_sample / len(data_loader.dataset)
    print("Accuracy : {}".format(accuracy))

data_loader_test = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mnist_test, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
mytest(model, data_loader_test)
```

> > Accuracy : 0.92232

**[ code 2 ]**

```
with torch.no_grad():
    x_test = mnist_test.test_data.view(-1,28*28).float().to(device)
    y_test = mnist_test.test_labels.to(device)

    prediction = model(x_test)
    correct_prediction = torch.argmax(prediction,1) == y_test
    accuracy = correct_prediction.float().mean()
    print("Accuracy ", accuracy.item())
```

> > Accuracy  0.8826999664306641

Comment: What is the shape of `mnist_test.test_data`? Is your model in eval mode?

Comment: The shape of mnist_test.test_data is [10000,28,28]. As trying eval mode, "model.eval()" doesn't matter. model is just "nn.Linear(784,10,bias=True)".

Comment: Can you show us the full code? (should be short enough) I cannot find anything wrong here.